# boto3: getting the list of access-levels in a policy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, permissions, boto3, policy

is there a way in boto3 to get the access level of a service in a policy (Full access, List, Tagging, Read, Write)? The allowed actions are too much, I just need the access levels.

For example I have the "IAMUserChangePassword"-Policy.
The allowed service in that policy is "IAM" and the access levels are "Read, Write". Now I want to write some python code to return a list of all access levels. I do not need the actions "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy, iam:ChangePassword", I just need the access levels.

Comment: Sorry, your question in unclear and lacks details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

While the IAM console does provide a 'user-friendly' version of policies by showing checkboxes with Read, Write, List, etc, this level of information is not available through an API. The console must have some additional logic that parses the policies to extract this information.